# Openlayers 3 - vector style problem

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, wfs

I wonder why the new style is not applied to the features of the vector. The code below works fine but the style is not applied.

```
var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
      $.ajax('http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs', {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          service: 'WFS',
          version: '1.1.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
          typename: 'placenames_medium',
          srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
          bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
      }).done(function(response) {
        layerWFS
        .getSource()
        .addFeatures(new ol.format.WFS()
          .readFeatures(response));
      });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
           radius: 3,
           fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'orange'}), 
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: 'black'})
        })
      })
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: [],
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    layerWFS
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
    zoom: 14
  })
});
```

Where is the problem?

I followed this example to apply the style: http://mappinggis.com/2016/06/anadir-wfs-en-openlayers-simbologia/

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ricopo/pen/GjRgam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

style should be defined on the layer not the source